# $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{2\cdot \ln(1+x)+x^2-2x}{x^3}$ without 'Hopital Rule

Tags: real-analysis, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Compute $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{(x+2)\cdot \ln(1+x)-2x}{x^3}$$ without L'Hopital Rule.

I proved before that  that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{ \ln(1+x)-x}{x^2}=-\frac{1}{2}$$

I tried to use it and I have to compute $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{2\cdot \ln(1+x)+x^2-2x}{x^3}$$

This limit looks easier to compute.

Comment: Sorry, I see what is going on.

Comment: The third limit is the third order approximation of $\ln(1+x)$ I think in might be a bit hard without l'Hopital or Taylor. How did you get the second limit anyway ?

Comment: @Rene Schipperus I denote it with $L$. Then $L=lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac {2x-ln (1+2x)}{4x^2} $. I compute $2L-L $ and then  I obtain $L=\frac {1}{2} $.

Comment: Ok, but the "fly in the ointment" with that approach is that it assumes that the limit exists. If you first try to prove that the limit exists, its really hard, and usually involves derivatives.

Comment: @Problemsolving Please remember that you can choose an aswer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 3):

Note that

$$\int_0^x{-t^3\over1+t}dt=\int_0^x\left({1\over1+t}-(1-t+t^2) \right)dt=\ln(1+x)-x+{1\over2}x^2-{1\over3}x^3$$

and thus

$$\lim_{x\to0}{2\ln(1+x)+x^2-2x\over x^3}={2\over3}+\lim_{x\to0}\left({-2\over x^3}\int_0^x{t^3\over1+t}dt\right)$$

For $|x|\lt1$, we have

$$0\le\left|{-2\over x^3}\int_0^x{t^3\over1+t}dt \right|\le{2\over |x|^3}\int_0^{|x|}{|x|^3\over1-|x|}dt={2|x|\over1-|x|}\to0\quad\text{as }x\to0$$

so by the Squeeze Theorem, we wind up with

$$\lim_{x\to0}{2\ln(1+x)+x^2-2x\over x^3}={2\over3}$$

Remark: The two keys here are 1) the integral definition of the natural logarithm, and 2) the expansion ${1\over1+t}=1-t+t^2-t^3+\cdots$, which can be truncated, with the appropriate adjustment, so as to give the opening expression.

Comment: OK fine, I get that you are answering the question asked. And there are good ideas in your answer. But to me it seems this is just way too complex an approach to such a limit that can be handled by a few simple applications, of L'Hopital. And again I know that was the question.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus, I agree, the most straightforward approach here is to L'Hopitate a time or two (or three). But for some reason the OP wants to compute the limit with that hand tied behind his or her back (as do many other users, on enough problems to warrant their own tag). I would argue that this may be the *simplest* approach that uses only basic notions of limits of functions, along with basic properties of the natural logarithm (i.e., its definition, more or less). But your point is well taken:  It may *seem* way more complex than the problem warrants.

Answer (score 1):

Use that
$$
2\ln(1+x)=2x-x^2+2\frac{x^3}{3}+o\left(x^3\right)
$$
Hence

> $$\frac{2\ln(1+x)+x^2-2x}{x^3}=\frac{2x^3+o\left(x^3\right)}{3x^3}\underset{x \rightarrow 0}{\rightarrow}\frac{2}{3}$$

Comment: You use Taylor expansion but I dont't know too many things about differentiability and I need a proof that use just notions from limits of functions.

Answer (score 1):

As shown, without l'Hopital, the limit can be solved easily by Taylor's expansion that is given the two following limits

- $\frac{\ln(1+x)-x}{x^2}\to -\frac12$ (as already mentioned)

and

- $\frac{\ln(1+x)-x+\frac{x^2}2}{x^3}\to \frac13$ (which correspond to to your second limit)

indeed by those limits, as you noticed, it follow that

$$\frac{(x+2)\cdot \ln(1+x)-2x}{x^3}=\frac{\ln(1+x)-x}{x^2}+\frac{2\cdot \ln(1+x)+x^2-2x}{x^3}\to-\frac12+\frac23=\frac16$$

Note that I've also tried by various manipulation as the following but I can't reach the result.

$$\frac{2\cdot \ln(1+x)+x^2-2x}{x^3}=\frac23\frac{3\ln(1+x)+\frac32x^2-3x}{x^3}=\frac23\frac{\ln(1+3x+3x^2+x^3)-(3x+3x^2+x^3)}{(3x+3x^2+x^3)^2}\frac{(3x+3x^2+x^3)^2}{x^3}+\frac23\frac{x^3+\frac92x^2}{x^3}$$